# htmlentities are breaking hyperlinks

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities

I am trying to do some htmlentities.  However, the hyperlinks are now broken due to them being converted to the html codes, wanting to do this as for some stupid reason the university has given us all the same password for the servers.

Last year I almost failed as someone went onto my server and filled with the javascript and css hacks, so this will prevent it, however it's not much use if the hyperlink won't work, so how do I prevent this? Here's the code I have so far for this specific area:

```
$sub = substr($row['content'],0,300).'.......... <a href="blogpost.php?id='.$row['id'].'">See full article</a>';
echo htmlentities($sub,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
```

If anyone can help, it's much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output, and what are you getting?

Comment: Can you please re-phrase your question? It is really, really hard to grasp what you are trying to do.

Comment: Before i added the htmlentities ot it this was the code

`echo substr($row['content'],0,300).'.......... <a href="blogpost.php?id='.$row['id'].'">See full article</a>';`

and that would output the hyperlink as normal so you can click on it and be taken to the page requested, now it just outputs the hyperlink like this

outputs!.......... <a href="blogpost.php?id=7">See full article</a>

Comment: Why would you not use `htmlentities` individually on `substr($row['content'],0,300)` , `$row['id']` before concatenation ?

Comment: ........OMFG @Uours that didn't even cross my mind :/ going to give it a go....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't apply `htmlentities` over the whole link, but on the values you actually want to escape, like this

```
$sub = htmlentities(substr($row['content'],0,300), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '.......... <a href="blogpost.php?id=' . htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') .'">See full article</a>';
echo $sub;
```

Comment: Whoa. A few seconds really can make a difference D:

Answer (score 3):

I think you're applying `htmlentities()` on too much of your output. Just do it like this:

```
<?php echo htmlentities(substr($row['content'],0,300)).
           '&hellip;<a href="blogpost.php?id="'.htmlentities($row['id']).'">See full article</a>'; ?>
```